# SAS Finding Last Year data from archive

Tags: sas

Good day, I am looking through an archive of policies and **want to create a variables (column) that shows the price of the policy from 1 year ago**.

Every policy has a Policy ID, and the archive has every policy (including renewals). So the same Policy ID can appear more than once in the archive but have different values in every other column. For example, say I have this

```
Policy_ID  Start_Date   End_Date   Premium  LYPremium15   LYPremium16  
1          01/01/2015  31/12/2015   500      .            .             
2          04/03/2015  03/03/2016   450      .            .             
3          03/02/2015  02/02/2016   600      .            .             
4          07/04/2015  06/04/2016   470      .            .             
5          01/01/2015  31/12/2015   500      .            .             
2          04/03/2016  03/03/2017   510      .            .
```

I would like to fill the columns LYPremium15, LYPremium16, LYPremium17 with the premium from the year before. So it will look like this,

```
Policy_ID  Start_Date   End_Date   Premium  LYPremium15   LYPremium16  
1          01/01/2015  31/12/2015   500      .            .             
2          04/03/2015  03/03/2016   450      .            .             
3          03/02/2015  02/02/2016   600      .            .             
4          07/04/2015  06/04/2016   470      .            .             
5          01/01/2015  31/12/2015   500      .            .             
2          04/03/2016  03/03/2017   510      450          .
```

Because Policy ID 2 is a renewal, so it does have data from last year. 
I am new to SAS, and not sure how I can code this. I was thinking of using **where** combined with **if** and **contains** but I am not sure that is an option. 
Can I use the standard way of creating variable?

```
data mylib.van_LYprem;
set mylib.van_combined_total;
LYPrem15=...;
run;
```

Or will I have to approach this in a more advanced way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAS will process your dataset record by records. So you will have to keep the old year values.

I assume the startdate is what determines the year.
If we sort the dataset like :

```
proc sort data=work.van_combined_total;
  by Policy_ID start_date;
run;
```

We can use a by statement and retain the values;

```
data work.van_LYprem;
  set work.van_combined_total;
  by Policy_ID start_date;

  retain LYPrem15 LYPrem16 LYPrem17;

    if (first.Policy_ID) then do;
       LYPrem15=.;
       LYPrem16=.;
       LYPrem17=.;
    end;

    output;

    if(year(start_date) eq 2015) then do;
         LYPrem15=Premium;
    end;
    if(year(start_date) eq 2016) then do;
        LYPrem16=Premium;
    end;
    if(year(start_date) eq 2017) then do;
        LYPrem17=Premium;
    end;     

run;
```

After this you will have records with premium and LYPremiumXX. If there are more renewals in 1 year you will only have the last value in LYPremiumXX...
You could make it more dynamic using macro's...

Comment: How about sorting based on Policy ID and using **lag** and **if** to simply look up the value from 1 (or perhaps 2) lines above?

Comment: Sure that would work too, if you don't care about the year but only the previous values. For an example you can check the SAS page [link] http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/63354/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0l66p5oqex1f2n1quuopdvtcjqb.htm